# Не отображается всплывающая форма

Tags: javascript, jquery, form

Есть всплывающая форма, когда нажимаю на кнопку то форма не открывается, ранее убирал hidden, после форма отображалась корректно, но перестала работать кнопка закрыть форму, помогите пожалуста как решить.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  function calcWindow() {
    $('#js-calculator-window').toggleClass('hidden')
    calcRe()
  }

  function calcRe() {
    var roomsCount = parseInt($('#rooms-count').val())
    var bathRoomsCount = parseInt($('#bathRoomsCount').val())
    var priceStandart = roomsCount + bathRoomsCount
    var priceAdditional = 0
    var priceTotal = 0
    $('#js-calculator-window .js-calculator-standart-service').each(function() {
      if (parseInt($(this).val()) > 0) {
        priceStandart += parseInt($(this).val())
      }
    })
    $('#js-calculator-window .custom-control-input').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        if ($('#cleaning-price-' + $(this).data('cleaning')).val() !== null) {
          priceAdditional += parseInt($('#cleaning-price-' + $(this).data('cleaning')).val())
        }
      }
    })
    priceTotal = parseInt(priceAdditional) + parseInt(priceStandart)
    $('#js-base-price').html('')
    $('#js-base-price').html(priceStandart)
    $('#js-additional-price').html('')
    $('#js-additional-price').html(priceAdditional)
    $('#js-final-price').html('')
    $('#js-final-price').html(priceTotal)
  }
  $('.custom-control-input').click(function() {
    calcRe()
  })
  $('#js-calculator-start').click(function() {
    calcWindow()
  })
  $('#js-calculator-window .close').click(function() {
    $('#js-calculator-window').toggleClass('hidden')
  })

  function sendOrder() {
    var phone = $('#js-calculator-phone').val()
    var name = $('#js-calculator-name').val()
    var time = $('#js-calculator-time').val()
    var roomsCount = parseInt($('#rooms-count').val())
    var bathRoomsCount = parseInt($('#bathRoomsCount').val())
    if (phone.length > 0 && name.length > 0) {
      var services = []
      $('#js-calculator-window .custom-control-input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          if ($('#cleaning-price-' + $(this).data('cleaning')).val() !== null) {
            services.push($('#cleaning-label-' + $(this).data('cleaning')).text())
          }
        }
      })
      var data = {
        'phone': phone,
        'name': name,
        'services': services,
        'roomsCount': roomsCount,
        'bathRoomsCount': bathRoomsCount
      }
      $.get('/api/calculator.php', {
        data: data
      }, function OnAjaxSuccessd(data) {
        $('.messengeArea').html('<p>Ваша заявка успешно отправлена!<br>В скором времени мы с вами свяжемся!</p>')
        $('.calculator-order').hide()
      })
    }
  }
  $('#js-send-calculator-data').click(function() {
    sendOrder()
  })
});
jQuery('document').ready(function($) {
  function modalCallback() {
    $('#js-modalCallback-overlay').toggleClass('hidden')
    $('#js-modalCallback-window').toggleClass('hidden')
  }
  $('.js-button-modal-callback').click(function() {
    modalCallback()
  })
  $('#js-modalCallback-window .close').click(function() {
    modalCallback()
  })

  function sendCallback() {
    var name = $('#js-modalCallback-name').val()
    var phone = $('#js-modalCallback-phone').val()
    if (name.length > 0 && phone.length > 0) {
      $.get('/api/form.php', {
        'name': name,
        'phone': phone
      }, function onAjaxSuccessd(data) {
        $('#js-modalCallback-body').html('<p>Ваша заявка успешно отправлена!<br>В скором времени мы с Вами свяжемся!')
      })
    }
  }
  $('#js-modalCallback-send').click(function() {
    sendCallback()
  })
});
jQuery('document').ready(function($) {
  $('#js-services-home li').click(function() {
    $('#js-services-home li').removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass('active')
    $('#services .service-item').addClass('hidden')
    $('#' + $(this).data('block')).removeClass('hidden')
  })
  jQuery('header img.icon').each(function() {
    var $img = jQuery(this);
    var imgID = $img.attr('id');
    var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
    var imgURL = $img.attr('src');
    jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
      var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');
      if (typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
        $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID)
      }
      if (typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
        $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass + ' replaced-svg')
      }
      $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');
      $img.replaceWith($svg)
    }, 'xml')
  })
});
jQuery('document').ready(function($) {
  $('.question').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active')
    $('#' + $(this).data('question')).toggleClass('hidden')
  })
});
jQuery('document').ready(function($) {
  $('#js-menu-select li').click(function() {
    $('#js-menu-select li').removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass('active')
    $('.menu-services .menu-body').addClass('hidden')
    $('#' + $(this).data('menu')).removeClass('hidden')
  })

  function menu() {
    $('#js-menu-services').toggleClass('hidden')
  }
  $('#js-menu-services .close').click(function() {
    menu()
  })
  $('.js-menu-button').click(function() {
    menu()
  })

  function scrolledMenu() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('.general-menu').addClass('scrolled')
    } else {
      $('.general-menu').removeClass('scrolled')
    }
  }
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    scrolledMenu()
  })
  scrolledMenu()
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fedora66.ru/wp-content/cache/fvm/1557815051/out/header-ed69676f.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-5 mx-auto text-center">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="rooms-count">
      <option value="1690"> 1-к квартира</option>
      <option value="2190"> 2-к квартира</option>
      <option value="2690"> 3-к квартира</option>
      <option value="3290"> 4-к квартира</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="bathRoomsCount">
      <option value="0">1 санузел</option>
      <option value="390">2 санузла</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-red" id="js-calculator-start" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#feedbackFormModal"> Рассчитать стоимость </button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="modal" id="feedbackFormModal" data-backdrop="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="calculator-overlay" id="js-calculator-window">
      <div class="calculator-window">
        <div class="close"></div>
        <div class="calculator-window-header">
          <h2>Онлайн калькулятор клининга</h2>
          <p>Вы можете добавить дополнительные услуги, отметив необходимые позиции в калькуляторе справа.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="messengeArea">
          <div class="calculator-window-body">
            <h4>По всей квартире</h4>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <h5>Входит в стоимость:</h5>
                <ul class="services-list">
                  <li> — Моем пол и протираем плинтусы <input type="hidden" class="js-calculator-standart-service" value=""></li>
                  <li> — Пылесосим ковры и коврики <input type="hidden" class="js-calculator-standart-service" value=""></li>
                  <li> — Протираем все доступные поверхности <input type="hidden" class="js-calculator-standart-service" value=""></li>
                  <li> — Протираем выключатели и дверные ручки <input type="hidden" class="js-calculator-standart-service" value=""></li>
                  <li> — Чистим зеркала и стеклянные поверхности <input type="hidden" class="js-calculator-standart-service" value=""></li>
                  <li> — Собираем и выносим мусор <input type="hidden" class="js-calculator-standart-service" value=""></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <h5>Дополнительно:</h5>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="cleaning-1" data-cleaning="1"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="cleaning-1">Мытье окон - 290р</label> <span class="hidden" id="cleaning-label-1">Мытье окон - 290р</span>
                  <input
                    type="hidden" id="cleaning-price-1" class="form-control" value="290"></div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="cleaning-2" data-cleaning="2"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="cleaning-2">Уборка балкона - 600р</label> <span class="hidden" id="cleaning-label-2">Уборка балкона - 600р</span>                  <input type="hidden" id="cleaning-price-2" class="form-control" value="600"></div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="cleaning-3" data-cleaning="3"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="cleaning-3">Мытье люстры - 500р</label> <span class="hidden" id="cleaning-label-3">Мытье люстры - 500р</span>                  <input type="hidden" id="cleaning-price-3" class="form-control" value="500"></div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="cleaning-4" data-cleaning="4"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="cleaning-4">Заберем ключи - 300р</label> <span class="hidden" id="cleaning-label-4">Заберем ключи - 300р</span>                  <input type="hidden" id="cleaning-price-4" class="form-control" value="300"></div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="cleaning-5" data-cleaning="5"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="cleaning-5">Доставим ключи - 300р</label> <span class="hidden" id="cleaning-label-5">Доставим ключи - 300р</span>                  <input type="hidden" id="cleaning-price-5" class="form-control" value="300"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="calculator-window-body">
            <h4>На кухне</h4>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <h5>Входит в стоимость:</h5>
                <ul class="services-list">
                  <li> — Моем раковину <input type="hidden" class="js-calculator-standart-service" value=""></li>
                  <li> — Протираем столешницу и кухонный фартук <input type="hidden" class="js-calculator-standart-service" value=""></li>
                  <li> — Моем снаружи плиту, холодильник и вытяжку <input type="hidden" class="js-calculator-standart-service" value=""></li>
                  <li> — Протираем фасады шкафов <input type="hidden" class="js-calculator-standart-service" value=""></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <h5>Дополнительно:</h5>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="cleaning-6" data-cleaning="6"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="cleaning-6">Моем посуду - 300р</label> <span class="hidden" id="cleaning-label-6">Моем посуду - 300р</span>                  <input type="hidden" id="cleaning-price-6" class="form-control" value="300"></div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="cleaning-7" data-cleaning="7"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="cleaning-7">Почистим холодильник - 450р</label> <span class="hidden" id="cleaning-label-7">Почистим холодильник - 450р</span>                  <input type="hidden" id="cleaning-price-7" class="form-control" value="450"></div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="cleaning-8" data-cleaning="8"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="cleaning-8">Помоем духовку - 400р</label> <span class="hidden" id="cleaning-label-8">Помоем духовку - 400р</span>                  <input type="hidden" id="cleaning-price-8" class="form-control" value="400"></div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="cleaning-9" data-cleaning="9"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="cleaning-9">Помоем микроволновку - 250р</label> <span class="hidden" id="cleaning-label-9">Помоем микроволновку - 250р</span>                  <input type="hidden" id="cleaning-price-9" class="form-control" value="250"></div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="cleaning-10" data-cleaning="10"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="cleaning-10">Приберём кухонные шкафы - 690р</label> <span class="hidden" id="cleaning-label-10">Приберём кухонные шкафы - 690р</span>                  <input type="hidden" id="cleaning-price-10" class="form-control" value="690"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="calculator-window-body">
            <h4>В ванной</h4>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <h5>Входит в стоимость:</h5>
                <ul class="services-list">
                  <li> — Чистим унитаз <input type="hidden" class="js-calculator-standart-service" value=""></li>
                  <li> — Моем ванну, душевую кабину и раковину <input type="hidden" class="js-calculator-standart-service" value=""></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <h5>Дополнительно:</h5>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="cleaning-11" data-cleaning="11"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="cleaning-11">Помоем лоток питомца - 300р</label> <span class="hidden" id="cleaning-label-11">Помоем лоток питомца - 300р</span>                  <input type="hidden" id="cleaning-price-11" class="form-control" value="300"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="calculator-footer">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4">
                <p>Базовая стоимость:<br><big id="js-base-price">1690</big>руб</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4">
                <p>За доп. услуги:<br><big id="js-additional-price">0</big>руб</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4">
                <p>Итого:<br><big id="js-final-price">1690</big>руб</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="calculator-order">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <p>Ваше имя:</p> <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" class="form-control" id="js-calculator-name"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <p>Номер телефона:</p> <input type="text" placeholder="+7(___)___-__-__" class="form-control js-phone" id="js-calculator-phone"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <p>Удобное время для звонка:</p>
                <select class="form-control" id="js-calculator-time">
                  <option value="1">Как можно скорее</option>
                  <option value="2">09:00-11:00</option>
                  <option value="3">11:00-13:00</option>
                  <option value="4">13:00-15:00</option>
                  <option value="5">15:00-17:00</option>
                  <option value="6">17:00-19:00</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4"> <button class="btn btn-block btn-send" id="js-send-calculator-data"> Оставить заявку </button></div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
              <p>Мы перезвоним Вам в течение часа после отправки заявки. Если вы оставляете заявку не в рабочее время, мы свяжемся в Вами на следующий рабочий день.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: "как решить" - открыть отладчик в браузере и поэтапно отладить код

Comment: @СергейМишин я делал так, в ошибки нечего не выходит

Comment: Ты не понял. Не ошибки посмотреть в консоли, а произвести отладку (debugging) - https://learn.javascript.ru/debugging-chrome

Comment: @СергейМишин у меня форма отображается если убрать класс .calculator-overlay.hidden {
    display: none;
}
Но после того как убрал hidden у меня перестает работать кнопка закрыть форму

Comment: Попробуй все обработчики в текущем виде заменить на "делегированные". То есть сейчас `...).click(...`, должно будет стать `$(селекторНЕИЗМЕНЯЕМОГОРодителя).on('click', 'селекторРебенка', function(...`

Comment: @СергейМишин не понял, у меня сейчас $('#js-calculator-window .close').click(function(){$('#js-calculator-window').toggleClass('hidden')})

Comment: вот я и говорю что надо через делегирование это делать, чтобы на динамической странице не попасть в ситуацию что что-то внезапно не работает

Answer (score 1):

Не правильно работает сам вызов модального окна. И у вас в файле `header-ed69676f.min.css` и в стилях bootstrap `div.modal` имеет свойство `display:none;` - его при клике и надо убирать. Тут вариантов несколько.. Или добавить стиль который будет перебивать сокрытие, к примеру:

```
.show {
    display:block !important;
}
```

И потом уже его использовать -> `$('.modal').toggleClass('show');`

Или второй вариант - заменить:

`$('#js-calculator-window').toggleClass('hidden');`

на

`$('.modal').css('display','block');...$('.modal').css('display','none')`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  function calcWindow() {
    $('.modal').css('display','block');
    calcRe();
  }

  function calcRe() {
    var roomsCount = parseInt($('#rooms-count').val())
    var bathRoomsCount = parseInt($('#bathRoomsCount').val())
    var priceStandart = roomsCount + bathRoomsCount
    var priceAdditional = 0
    var priceTotal = 0
    $('#js-calculator-window .js-calculator-standart-service').each(function() {
      if (parseInt($(this).val()) > 0) {
        priceStandart += parseInt($(this).val())
      }
    })
    $('#js-calculator-window .custom-control-input').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        if ($('#cleaning-price-' + $(this).data('cleaning')).val() !== null) {
          priceAdditional += parseInt($('#cleaning-price-' + $(this).data('cleaning')).val())
        }
      }
    })
    priceTotal = parseInt(priceAdditional) + parseInt(priceStandart)
    $('#js-base-price').html('')
    $('#js-base-price').html(priceStandart)
    $('#js-additional-price').html('')
    $('#js-additional-price').html(priceAdditional)
    $('#js-final-price').html('')
    $('#js-final-price').html(priceTotal)
  }
  $('.custom-control-input').click(function() {
    calcRe()
  })
  $('#js-calculator-start').click(function() {
    calcWindow()
  })
  $('#js-calculator-window .close').click(function() {
    $('.modal').css('display','none')
  })

  function sendOrder() {
    var phone = $('#js-calculator-phone').val()
    var name = $('#js-calculator-name').val()
    var time = $('#js-calculator-time').val()
    var roomsCount = parseInt($('#rooms-count').val())
    var bathRoomsCount = parseInt($('#bathRoomsCount').val())
    if (phone.length > 0 && name.length > 0) {
      var services = []
      $('#js-calculator-window .custom-control-input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          if ($('#cleaning-price-' + $(this).data('cleaning')).val() !== null) {
            services.push($('#cleaning-label-' + $(this).data('cleaning')).text())
          }
        }
      })
      var data = {
        'phone': phone,
        'name': name,
        'services': services,
        'roomsCount': roomsCount,
        'bathRoomsCount': bathRoomsCount
      }
      $.get('/api/calculator.php', {
        data: data
      }, function OnAjaxSuccessd(data) {
        $('.messengeArea').html('<p>Ваша заявка успешно отправлена!<br>В скором времени мы с вами свяжемся!</p>')
        $('.calculator-order').hide()
      })
    }
  }
  $('#js-send-calculator-data').click(function() {
    sendOrder()
  })
});
jQuery('document').ready(function($) {
  function modalCallback() {
    $('#js-modalCallback-overlay').toggleClass('hidden')
    $('#js-modalCallback-window').toggleClass('hidden')
  }
  $('.js-button-modal-callback').click(function() {
    modalCallback()
  })
  $('#js-modalCallback-window .close').click(function() {
    modalCallback()
  })

  function sendCallback() {
    var name = $('#js-modalCallback-name').val()
    var phone = $('#js-modalCallback-phone').val()
    if (name.length > 0 && phone.length > 0) {
      $.get('/api/form.php', {
        'name': name,
        'phone': phone
      }, function onAjaxSuccessd(data) {
        $('#js-modalCallback-body').html('<p>Ваша заявка успешно отправлена!<br>В скором времени мы с Вами свяжемся!')
      })
    }
  }
  $('#js-modalCallback-send').click(function() {
    sendCallback()
  })
});
jQuery('document').ready(function($) {
  $('#js-services-home li').click(function() {
    $('#js-services-home li').removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass('active')
    $('#services .service-item').addClass('hidden')
    $('#' + $(this).data('block')).removeClass('hidden')
  })
  jQuery('header img.icon').each(function() {
    var $img = jQuery(this);
    var imgID = $img.attr('id');
    var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
    var imgURL = $img.attr('src');
    jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
      var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');
      if (typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
        $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID)
      }
      if (typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
        $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass + ' replaced-svg')
      }
      $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');
      $img.replaceWith($svg)
    }, 'xml')
  })
});
jQuery('document').ready(function($) {
  $('.question').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active')
    $('#' + $(this).data('question')).toggleClass('hidden')
  })
});
jQuery('document').ready(function($) {
  $('#js-menu-select li').click(function() {
    $('#js-menu-select li').removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass('active')
    $('.menu-services .menu-body').addClass('hidden')
    $('#' + $(this).data('menu')).removeClass('hidden')
  })

  function menu() {
    $('#js-menu-services').toggleClass('hidden')
  }
  $('#js-menu-services .close').click(function() {
    menu()
  })
  $('.js-menu-button').click(function() {
    menu()
  })

  function scrolledMenu() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('.general-menu').addClass('scrolled')
    } else {
      $('.general-menu').removeClass('scrolled')
    }
  }
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    scrolledMenu()
  })
  scrolledMenu()
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fedora66.ru/wp-content/cache/fvm/1557815051/out/header-ed69676f.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-5 mx-auto text-center">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="rooms-count">
      <option value="1690"> 1-к квартира</option>
      <option value="2190"> 2-к квартира</option>
      <option value="2690"> 3-к квартира</option>
      <option value="3290"> 4-к квартира</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="bathRoomsCount">
      <option value="0">1 санузел</option>
      <option value="390">2 санузла</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-red" id="js-calculator-start" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#feedbackFormModal"> Рассчитать стоимость </button>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="modal" id="feedbackFormModal" data-backdrop="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="calculator-overlay" id="js-calculator-window">
      <div class="calculator-window">
        <div class="close"></div>
        <div class="calculator-window-header">
          <h2>Онлайн калькулятор клининга</h2>
          <p>Вы можете добавить дополнительные услуги, отметив необходимые позиции в калькуляторе справа.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="messengeArea">
          <div class="calculator-window-body">
            <h4>По всей квартире</h4>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <h5>Входит в стоимость:</h5>
                <ul class="services-list">
                  <li> — Моем пол и протираем плинтусы <input type="hidden" class="js-calculator-standart-service" value=""></li>
                  <li> — Пылесосим ковры и коврики <input type="hidden" class="js-calculator-standart-service" value=""></li>
                  <li> — Протираем все доступные поверхности <input type="hidden" class="js-calculator-standart-service" value=""></li>
                  <li> — Протираем выключатели и дверные ручки <input type="hidden" class="js-calculator-standart-service" value=""></li>
                  <li> — Чистим зеркала и стеклянные поверхности <input type="hidden" class="js-calculator-standart-service" value=""></li>
                  <li> — Собираем и выносим мусор <input type="hidden" class="js-calculator-standart-service" value=""></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <h5>Дополнительно:</h5>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="cleaning-1" data-cleaning="1"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="cleaning-1">Мытье окон - 290р</label> <span class="hidden" id="cleaning-label-1">Мытье окон - 290р</span>
                  <input
                    type="hidden" id="cleaning-price-1" class="form-control" value="290"></div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="cleaning-2" data-cleaning="2"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="cleaning-2">Уборка балкона - 600р</label> <span class="hidden" id="cleaning-label-2">Уборка балкона - 600р</span>                  <input type="hidden" id="cleaning-price-2" class="form-control" value="600"></div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="cleaning-3" data-cleaning="3"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="cleaning-3">Мытье люстры - 500р</label> <span class="hidden" id="cleaning-label-3">Мытье люстры - 500р</span>                  <input type="hidden" id="cleaning-price-3" class="form-control" value="500"></div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="cleaning-4" data-cleaning="4"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="cleaning-4">Заберем ключи - 300р</label> <span class="hidden" id="cleaning-label-4">Заберем ключи - 300р</span>                  <input type="hidden" id="cleaning-price-4" class="form-control" value="300"></div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="cleaning-5" data-cleaning="5"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="cleaning-5">Доставим ключи - 300р</label> <span class="hidden" id="cleaning-label-5">Доставим ключи - 300р</span>                  <input type="hidden" id="cleaning-price-5" class="form-control" value="300"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="calculator-window-body">
            <h4>На кухне</h4>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <h5>Входит в стоимость:</h5>
                <ul class="services-list">
                  <li> — Моем раковину <input type="hidden" class="js-calculator-standart-service" value=""></li>
                  <li> — Протираем столешницу и кухонный фартук <input type="hidden" class="js-calculator-standart-service" value=""></li>
                  <li> — Моем снаружи плиту, холодильник и вытяжку <input type="hidden" class="js-calculator-standart-service" value=""></li>
                  <li> — Протираем фасады шкафов <input type="hidden" class="js-calculator-standart-service" value=""></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <h5>Дополнительно:</h5>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="cleaning-6" data-cleaning="6"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="cleaning-6">Моем посуду - 300р</label> <span class="hidden" id="cleaning-label-6">Моем посуду - 300р</span>                  <input type="hidden" id="cleaning-price-6" class="form-control" value="300"></div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="cleaning-7" data-cleaning="7"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="cleaning-7">Почистим холодильник - 450р</label> <span class="hidden" id="cleaning-label-7">Почистим холодильник - 450р</span>                  <input type="hidden" id="cleaning-price-7" class="form-control" value="450"></div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="cleaning-8" data-cleaning="8"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="cleaning-8">Помоем духовку - 400р</label> <span class="hidden" id="cleaning-label-8">Помоем духовку - 400р</span>                  <input type="hidden" id="cleaning-price-8" class="form-control" value="400"></div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="cleaning-9" data-cleaning="9"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="cleaning-9">Помоем микроволновку - 250р</label> <span class="hidden" id="cleaning-label-9">Помоем микроволновку - 250р</span>                  <input type="hidden" id="cleaning-price-9" class="form-control" value="250"></div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="cleaning-10" data-cleaning="10"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="cleaning-10">Приберём кухонные шкафы - 690р</label> <span class="hidden" id="cleaning-label-10">Приберём кухонные шкафы - 690р</span>                  <input type="hidden" id="cleaning-price-10" class="form-control" value="690"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="calculator-window-body">
            <h4>В ванной</h4>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <h5>Входит в стоимость:</h5>
                <ul class="services-list">
                  <li> — Чистим унитаз <input type="hidden" class="js-calculator-standart-service" value=""></li>
                  <li> — Моем ванну, душевую кабину и раковину <input type="hidden" class="js-calculator-standart-service" value=""></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <h5>Дополнительно:</h5>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="cleaning-11" data-cleaning="11"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="cleaning-11">Помоем лоток питомца - 300р</label> <span class="hidden" id="cleaning-label-11">Помоем лоток питомца - 300р</span>                  <input type="hidden" id="cleaning-price-11" class="form-control" value="300"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="calculator-footer">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4">
                <p>Базовая стоимость:<br><big id="js-base-price">1690</big>руб</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4">
                <p>За доп. услуги:<br><big id="js-additional-price">0</big>руб</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4">
                <p>Итого:<br><big id="js-final-price">1690</big>руб</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="calculator-order">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <p>Ваше имя:</p> <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" class="form-control" id="js-calculator-name"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <p>Номер телефона:</p> <input type="text" placeholder="+7(___)___-__-__" class="form-control js-phone" id="js-calculator-phone"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <p>Удобное время для звонка:</p>
                <select class="form-control" id="js-calculator-time">
                  <option value="1">Как можно скорее</option>
                  <option value="2">09:00-11:00</option>
                  <option value="3">11:00-13:00</option>
                  <option value="4">13:00-15:00</option>
                  <option value="5">15:00-17:00</option>
                  <option value="6">17:00-19:00</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4"> <button class="btn btn-block btn-send" id="js-send-calculator-data"> Оставить заявку </button></div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
              <p>Мы перезвоним Вам в течение часа после отправки заявки. Если вы оставляете заявку не в рабочее время, мы свяжемся в Вами на следующий рабочий день.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: сработало, форма закрывается, но когда я хочу открыть форму, у меня открывается другая форма

Comment: @fermeg А у вас часом id элементов в разных формах не повторяются?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin не повторяются, так как при открыл и закрыл все ок, но когда повторно нажимаю то открывается другая форма

Comment: Не удаётся воспроизвести вашу ошибку.. Закрываю открываю и всё та же форма показывается (chrome,safari,ff)

Comment: @InDevX ссылка на сайт greencleaning66.ru

Comment: да, как [@KirillKorushkin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/236197/kirill-korushkin) и написал, у вас одинаковые идентификаторы для этой формы а той что в меню вверху ("Оставить услугу"), отсюда и баг

Comment: @InDevX баг в том что при повторном нажатии, необходимо 2 раза нажать на кнопку